pm2 not startng a nodejs express application properly on AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2
I have an AWS EC2 instance running AmazonLinux2, where I want to launch a nodejs express application. Everything worked fine until I had to run the appplication with PM2 with sudo, as I am running it on port 443. I launch it with the command
 sudo "$(which node)" "$(which pm2)" start server.js
which seems to work until i noticed it is not being assigned a PID or take any CPU/MEM.
When I run it on another port such as 5050, where I do not need sudo to launch pm2, it works fine, however I believe if I configure my Roue53 to route my domain to 5050 with ssl, i would still need sudo permissions.
The express application is a simple https website listening on 443. It works perfectly fine when simply launched as
sudo $(which node) server.js.
pm2 logs only warn of my nodejs being v17.0.0 however i dont believe it is the problem as it works fine when working on port 5050 without sudo.
Could you tell me what could possibly be the problem? Or may be i need to find some workaraound.
Thank you!
I tried running it as root/sudo, reassigning ports - however port 443 is the one used for ssl connections. I suspect the problem lies in the pm2 program, but dont know where exactly.

Hi @LeEmpereur , I have deployed nodejs in ec2 using pm2 and I remember there are two default user in ec2, either run pm2 on same user or try to give access to your another user where pm2 is running, I am not sure if it will help you but you can give it try. Thanks.

Running node as root is not a good idea - but to bind node to ports below 1024 requires a privialged user. A common pattern to solve this problem is to run node un-privileged port and then use either a local webserver that reverse proxies port 5050 to to port 443, or if your using a load balencer you can configure the target group to use 5050 but listen on 443.
